# Count how many posts a user has viewed

Tags: posts, users, views

Seems this is quite a new question, as I found it nowhere.
I was wondering if it is possible to count how many posts a registered user has viewed (entered) on the frontend. 
 So basically when a user enters a post, the counter will add 1. Unique views, so if he enters the same post again it won't be counted.

thanks!

Comment: I guess nobody knows this :)

Comment: yes it is possible but only if you force your users to login to read the site.

Comment: yes, that is not the problem. the problems is...what is the code for this